# Python ImportError: cannot import name 'Uniswap'

Tags: python, import, libraries

Have Problem
fresh install Ubuntu 18 64bit

```
apt-get update
apt install python3-pip
alias pip=pip3
pip install uniswap-python

root@ubuntu:~# python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

from uniswap import Uniswap
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
ImportError: cannot import name 'Uniswap'
```

what can i do please help

Comment: Try this `pip install uniswap` (without `-python`).